# Application to transfer files via Wi-fi direct or other p2p solution

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I want to create an application that would allow sharing files across multiple devices via p2p connection. The first thing I wanted to research was Wi-fi direct as I remember it from back in the day. But I'm not sure it would be the best solution for cross-platform file transfers. I need the app to transfer images from the phone to the laptop and vice versa. The general idea is to have something completely seamless like Airdrop that would be able to transfer images in one click from a windows/Mac/Linux machine. What would be the best solution for cross-platform file transfer with wifi capabilities (on the same network)